# Shell script or c++ library for viewing internet connections and build a firewall

Tags: c++, security, shell, ubuntu, firewall

**(I Use Ubuntu)**

I'm looking for some pointers for writing a firewall program which denies every port/ip at first and creates rules by asking you whenever a program wants to access the internet, much like the discontinued product Kaspersky Anti Hacker for Windows. I especially want to use it on web browsing. So if my web browser wants to access stackoverflow.com the program should ask me if it should make a connection to stackoverflow.com's ip address, or when torrent client wants to connect a peer It should ask to either allow that port or allow that ip/port only.

I have used gufw but I have to know the port/ip before adding the rules so it isn't as I want it to be. I'm also trying to stay out of Firestarter since the last release was in 2005. So I have decided to write my own.

I just need some pointers on this subject. It can be a terminal command to see the connections I make with other computers, or a way to prompt before making connections, an open source project that sounds like this, or a c++ library/shell program that I can use to write a program for this... Any lead at all would suffice.

If you could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

PS. I am familiar with c++ and shell and php but that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, you seem to be interested in Windows only. If so, you might wish to look at Windows Layered Socket Providers (LSP) infrastructure.

In short, you can write DLL, which would be automatically loaded into any application that uses Winsock. This DLL can intercept calls to any Winsock function like `connect()`, `send()` and etc. When such call is intercepted you can show user some window asking if he wish to connect to this address.

So, this can be used to build such firewall application you are thinking of.

There should be a lot of documentation on how to create LSP's on Microsoft site, but i remember especially nice example by Komodia company - http://www.komodia.com/lsp/lsp-sample.

Comment: Actually I use ubuntu, I'm looking resources for linux. My bad, I added it on the top of the post now...

Comment: Then i can only recommend you `libpcap` project, which would allow you to sniff internet traffic.